# two- and three-digit footnote numbers ragged right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

here is a publisher’s request I wasn’t able to fulfill... Footnote numbers are supposed to be ragged right in line with the left margin. After every number a skip of »--« (\enskip ?). Here is a try that looks good for one digit (but still isn’t correct) but is wrong for two and three digits.

```
\documentclass[english,showframe]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}

\deffootnote[0.5em]{0em}{1em}{\raggedright{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
Some text.\footnote{Text.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext \footnote{\blindtext}
\setcounter{footnote}{10}
\footnote{Test}
\setcounter{footnote}{100}
\footnote{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your title you say ragged left but in your question you say ragged right. Which is it?

Comment: I mean ragged right for the numbers. 

Sorry, that was a confusion because of the German »linksbündig«. Edited the question

Comment: So the indent from the left margin to the start of the note text needs to vary? If so, I think you will need to redefine KOMA's creation of footnotes and not just customise the marker.

Comment: Could you confirm that the text is being typeset in `lmodern`'s defaults? If so, you might be able to do something tricky to get the desired effect. (Note that this means you are **not** using `cfr-lm`'s defaults or, for that matter, another set of fonts entirely.)

Comment: But it is probably easier to just redefine `\footnote` ....

Comment: Thank you cfr. Yes, the space where the first line of the footnote text begins has to vary according to the digits of the footnote number. That’s the task. In the end I will use palatino. Not sure if that answers your questions though. Should I change my MWE? How could I redefine \footnote to get the effect. I didn’t find solutions (or maybe I just didn’t understand them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't guarantee this at all. It survives **extremely** minimal testing i.e. your example seems to work, if I've understood your desiderata.

## *Caveat emptor*

```
\documentclass[british,showframe]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\deffootnote[4][]{%
  \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
    \raggedfootnote 
    \leftskip #2 
    \l@addto@macro\@trivlist{%
      \ifnum\@listdepth=\@ne\advance\leftmargin #2\relax\fi
    }%
    \parindent #3 \noindent
    \ftn@font{\@@makefnmark##1}%
  }%
  \def\@@makefnmark{%
    \ftnm@font{#4}%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{}{%
      \hskip \dimexpr #1-#2\relax
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\deffootnote[.5em]{0em}{1em}{\raggedright{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
Some text.\footnote{Text.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext \footnote{\blindtext}
\setcounter{footnote}{10}
\footnote{Test}
\setcounter{footnote}{100}
\footnote{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image: unboxed footnote markers]